# Implement dropout to fully connected layer in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, dropout

How to apply dropout to the following fully connected network in Pytorch:

```
class NetworkRelu(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(784,128)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128,64)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(64,10)


    def forward(self,x):
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = F.softmax(self.fc3(x),dim=1)
        return x
```

Answer (score 13):

Since there is functional code in the forward method, you could use functional dropout, however, it would be better to use `nn.Module` in `__init__()` so that the model when set to `model.eval()` evaluate mode automatically turns off the dropout.

Here is the code to implement dropout:

```
class NetworkRelu(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(784,128)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128,64)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(64,10)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=0.5)

    def forward(self,x):
        x = self.dropout(F.relu(self.fc1(x)))
        x = self.dropout(F.relu(self.fc2(x)))
        x = F.softmax(self.fc3(x),dim=1)
        return x
```

Comment: we can also use same `dropout` object multiple times as you did in the example, right? no need for creating `self.dropout2 = nn.Dropout(p=0.5)` for the 2nd line in forward,  `x = self.dropout2(F.relu(self.fc2(x)))`

Comment: @patti_jane Yes we can use same `dropout` object multiple times.